# How to require approval around adding users to SP groups?

Tags: 2007, workflow, permissions, site, content-approval

We have a site owner who we want to be able to create lists, etc. and assign SharePoint groups to have access to them. However, we need to verify (approve) the people she wants to add to those groups or areas. Is there any way to launch a workflow or handle the addition of a new user or group and have it not apply until someone else approves it?

I realize we could take away the permissions role for the site owner but then she wouldn't be able to create new libraries and assign existing (or new) SP groups to it.

This is a MOSS site.

Thanks,
Phil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, if the user is going to be creating and managing permissions, then that comes with the territory.  Full Control grants this right so being listed as such gives them the trust that the permissions changes they are doing are desirable.

If you're really that concerned, then give her Contribute or Design rights on the site and manage the security yourselves or give her some guidance and training to ensure that both you and her are in agreement about permissions.

Comment: Thanks. Does Design rights give her the ability to create new subsites or document libraries? If so, does that mean that all the permissions in those new items are purely inherited (because she can't actually assign rights)?

Comment: Design will give her the ability to add document libraries but not subsites.  You could create a custom Design permission level that allowed for the creation of subsites and in that case, it should inherit the parent permissions as she would not have the ability to Manage Permissions.